# Improving query performance by example

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I'm trying to think out a way to improve a query the consumed schema is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `billing_profile_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `billing_address_id` INTEGER NULL,
  `total` DECIMAL(8, 2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `billing_profiles` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `billing_addresses` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address` TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `stores` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

The query I'm executing:

```
SELECT bp.name,
       ba.address,
       s.name,
       Sum(o.total) AS total
FROM   billing_profiles bp,
       stores s,
       orders o
       LEFT JOIN billing_addresses ba
              ON o.billing_address_id = ba.id
WHERE  o.billing_profile_id = bp.id
       AND s.id = o.store_id
GROUP  BY bp.name,
          ba.address,
          s.name;
```

And here is the `EXPLAIN`:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                          | rows  | filtered | Extra                                      |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bp    | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                         |155000 |   100.00 | Using temporary                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                         |220000 |    33.33 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ba    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | factory.o.billing_address_id |    1  |   100.00 | NULL                                       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | factory.o.store_id           |    1  |   100.00 | NULL                                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

The problem I'm facing is that this query takes 30+ secs to excute, we have over 200000 orders, and 150000+ billing_profiles/billing_addresses.

What should I do regarding index/constraints so that this query becomes faster to execute?

**Edit:** after some suggestions in the comments I edited the query to:

```
SELECT bp.name,
       ba.address,
       s.name,
       Sum(o.total) AS total
FROM   orders o
       INNER JOIN billing_profiles bp
               ON o.billing_profile_id = bp.id
       INNER JOIN stores s
               ON s.id = o.store_id
       LEFT JOIN billing_addresses ba
              ON o.billing_address_id = ba.id
GROUP  BY bp.name,
          ba.address,
          s.name;
```

But still takes too much time.

Comment: The first thing you should do is look at the query plan (EXPLAIN) of the query you want to optimize

Comment: I will add that info @SergioTulentsev

Comment: ' If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html - best use explicit joins throughout.

Comment: If your database contains hundreds of thousands of records, does it make sense to sum them **all** up without filtering?

Comment: A `FROM x, y, z` will likely do a cartesian join - you probably want to make those `LEFT JOIN`s when possible.

Comment: @AKX thank you, I edited the query above with your suggestions, still the same problem.

Comment: I'd try adding an index on store_id

Comment: "still takes too much time."  How much time does it take, and how much time would you like it to take?

Comment: @AndyLester roughly the same (30 secs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I have used in the past and has helped in many instances with MySQL is to use the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` clause which tells the engine to do the query in the order as listed.

I have cleaned-up your query to proper JOIN context.  Since the ORDER table is the primary basis of data, and the other 3 are lookup references to their respective IDs, I put the ORDER table first.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
        bp.name,
        ba.address,
        s.name,
        Sum(o.total) AS total
    FROM
        orders o
            JOIN stores s
                ON o.store_id = s.id
            JOIN billing_profiles bp
                on o.billing_profile_id = bp.id
            LEFT JOIN billing_addresses ba
                ON o.billing_address_id = ba.id
    GROUP BY 
        bp.name,
        ba.address,
        s.name
```

Now, your data tables dont appear that large, but if you are going to be grouping by 3 of the columns in the order table, I would have an index on the underlying basis of them, which are the "ID" keys linking to the other tables.  Adding the total to help for a covering index / aggregate query, I would index on

```
( store_id, billing_profile_id, billing_address_id, total )
```

I'm sure that in reality, you have many other columns associated with an order and just showing the context for this query.  Then, I would change to a pre-query so the aggregation is all done once for the orders table by their ID keys, THEN the result is joined to the lookup tables and you just need to apply an ORDER BY clause for your final output.  Something like..

```
SELECT
        bp.name,
        ba.address,
        s.name,
        o.total
    FROM
        ( select
                store_id,
                billing_profile_id,
                billing_address_id,
                sum( total ) total 
            from
                orders 
            group by
                store_id,
                billing_profile_id,
                billing_address_id ) o
    JOIN stores s
        ON o.store_id = s.id
    JOIN billing_profiles bp
        on o.billing_profile_id = bp.id
    LEFT JOIN billing_addresses ba
        ON o.billing_address_id = ba.id
    ORDER BY 
        bp.name,
        ba.address,
        s.name
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I add one index for all: `ALTER TABLE orders ADD INDEX order_master_idx ( store_id, billing_profile_id, billing_address_id, total )`. Or one for each?

Comment: Index hints (eg, `STRAIGHT_JOIN`) may "help to day, but hurt tomorrow".

Comment: @ManuelSimões, one index including ALL the fields at once.

Comment: @RickJames, from the times I've used, when dealing with secondary (lookup) tables, by having the primary table in first position has always (for me) proved to help performance when lagging otherwise.  But, I dont doubt there may be issues such as deprecation of STRAIGHT_JOIN in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**Add this index** to `o`, being sure to start with `billing_profile_id`:

```
INDEX(billing_profile_id, store_id, billing_address_id, total)
```

**Discussion of the Explain:**

- The Optimizer saw that it needed to do a full scan of *some* table.
- `bp` was smaller than `o`, so it picked `bp` as the "first" table.
- Then it reached into the next table repeatedly.
- It did not see a suitable index (one starting with `billing_profile_id`) and decided to do "Using join buffer (hash join)", which involves loading the entire table into a hash in RAM.
- "Using temporary", though mentioned on the "first" table, really does not show up until just before the `GROUP BY`.  (The `GROUP BY` references multiple tables, so there is no way to optimize it.)

**Potential bug**  Please check the results of `Sum(o.total) AS total`.  It is performed *after* all the `JOINing` and *before* the `GROUP BY`, so it *may* be inflated.  Notice how DRapp's formulation does the `SUM` *before* the JOINs.